# MUSL C library does not work yocto project

Tags: git, arm, embedded-linux, yocto, musl

I'm using **yocto project** to build linux kernel for my **sama5d27 som1 board**. I'm trying to reduce the size of the released kernel so I replaced sysVinit to **busybox init** and now I am trying to replace gClibrary with **musl C library**.

Under my Poky directory I cloned meta-musl layer using:

**git clone git://github.com/kraj/meta-musl.git**

I added the layer to `bblayers.conf` and also added `TCLIBC = "musl"` to local.conf
I initialized the environment and then run `bitbake core-image-minimal`

I got these errors:

> **ERROR:** systemd-1_237-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log
>   file is located at
>   /home/gaston/linux4sam/poky/build-microchip/tmp/work/cortexa5t2hf-neon-poky-linux-musleabi/systemd/1_237-r0/temp/log.do_compile.6846)
>
> **ERROR:** Logfile of failure stored in:
>   /home/gaston/linux4sam/poky/build-microchip/tmp/work/cortexa5t2hf-neon-poky-linux-musleabi/systemd/1_237-r0/temp/log.do_compile.6846
>
> **ERROR:** Task
>   (/home/gaston/linux4sam/poky/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_237.bb:do_compile)
>   failed with exit code '1'

Could you please help me out ?

Comment: post `log.do_compile.6846` or at least its part with the compilation error.

Comment: I checked log.do_compile and its a sort of my terminal when it's building the linux image and it's ended with these same errors described above. I did not put meta-musl in bblayers.conf, i just put TCLIBC = "musl" in local.conf

Comment: this is very unlikely; look more careful - there should be the exact reason it fails to compile.

Comment: or post the entire file on pastebin or wherever.

Comment: maybe there is a relation between systemd init and musl C lib ? because i have replcaed systemd by busybox init system

Comment: post `do_compile.6846` and `local.conf`. it's hard to guess without having any info.

Comment: I don't know how to post a file on stackoverflow. I will try to fix the error. If it fails i will use poky-tiny or i will delete some distro features to make a smaller rootfs

Comment: use pastebin or any service alike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong, but it looks like `meta-musl` is something that was made for Yocto before `musl` was integrated into the project.

You can see the meta-layer has not been updated in 4 years. Just add `TCLIBC = "musl"` to your project's config and use what is available in Yocto now.

Comment: Thank you. It works now. I added this in local.conf : DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "systemd" and I think this solved systemd do_compile error